# Angularjs bootstrap range Rz-Slider width issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

[image]I am creating a range slider with steps array, while on page load sometimes it comes in full width sometime times it does not. When it loads with an incorrect width and I click on any of the range it shows in proper format. I even tried to click on any one range by using jquery but nothing works. Is there a way to pass width in options
Below is my code in view and controller

```
<rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue" rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="slider.options" ></rzslider>

$scope.slider = {
        minValue: 2,
        maxValue: 12,

        options: {
           floor: 0,
        ceil: 33,
        //showTicks: true,
        showTicksValues :true,
        stepsArray: [
            {value: 1, legend: 'Confirmed'},
            {value: 2, legend: 'Assessed'},
            {value: 3, legend: 'Approved'},
            {value: 4, legend: 'Quoted  '},
            {value: 5, legend: 'Office A1'},
            {value: 6, legend: 'Whoops do over'},
            {value: 7, legend: 'Office A2'},
            {value: 8, legend: 'Ticketed waiting to quote'},
            {value: 9, legend: 'Waiting for client approval'}, 
            {value: 10, legend: 'Awaiting A2 quote'},
            {value: 11, legend: 'Determining approach'},  
            {value: 12, legend: 'Awaiting key material(s)'},
            {value: 13, legend: 'Declined'},
            {value: 14, legend: 'A1 Cleaning WIP'},
            {value: 15, legend: 'A1 Restoration queue'},  
            {value: 16, legend: 'A2 to A1 post process'}, 
            {value: 17, legend: 'A2 to A1 restoration'},  
            {value: 18, legend: 'A1 Restoration WIP'},
            {value: 19, legend: 'Completed'},
            {value: 20, legend: 'Return scheduled'},
            {value: 21, legend: 'Returned'},
            {value: 22, legend: 'Invoiced'},
            {value: 23, legend: 'Closed happy'},
            {value: 24, legend: 'Closed so-so'},
        ],
    }


};
```

Comment: having a minimal working demo here would be easier to test/resolve

Comment: thanks for your time, i got a solution by using setTimeout(function() 
   {
    $scope.$broadcast('rzSliderForceRender');
   },500);